# Google Chrome problem with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

When I log into Google Chrome with my email address after shutdown, when I start back up Google Chrome is replaced with Yahoo and something called Fox find.

When this happens and I don't log into Chrome and just use Mozilla Foxfire, I can't view video on Facebook or Yahoo. It says Flash needs to be installed. I've tried that and still cannot play videos

Comment: It probably has to do with settings synced through your Google account. Open *Settings -> Sign in -> Advanced sync settings* and turn off anything you don't want synced. To fix the flash issue run: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 0):

1 - install flash plugin for videos

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

2 - how to reset chrome 
Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar [image]

Select Settings.
Click Show advanced settings and find the "Reset browser settings” section.
Click Reset browser settings.
In the dialog that appears, click Reset.